# Transitive dependency pulling in lower version than declared in POM

Tags: maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-restdocs

I am using version 1.2.2 of `spring-restdocs-mockmvc` in my Spring Boot application that I am developing with IntelliJ.

[image]

Taking a look at its POM, it declares the following dependency of `spring-restdocs-core`:

[image]

But for some reason, the compile version of `spring-restdocs-core` available to me during development does not match this, and keeps me stuck on version 1.1.2.

[image]

I have updated my repositories, refreshed, rebuilt, clean install, you name it, everything I could find on how to "refresh" the state of my Maven project, and nothing changes this. Any ideas?

Comment: run mvn dependency:tree, and find out which other dependency has this dependency.

Comment: Check the dependency tree, who else adds `spring-restdocs-core`, maybe someone (closer to your project) overrides the version. Check your `dependencyManagement` whether it's overridden there. If you have a Maven parent (eg. Spring-Boot-parent) check the version defined there. These can all override a dependency version.

Comment: If you have `spring-boot-starter-parent` dependency, you should not try to override the managed version (so don't add the version when adding the dependency), otherwise the dependency versions can be different.
If you manually want to override, you have to define `spring-restdocs-core` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a blog post [here](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot) on spring.io that captures the issues pretty well and offers five different possible solutions from doing some XML sit ups with Maven to migrating your build to Gradle (thus dodging XML sit ups altogether). Looks like what that post presents as "option 2" might be the easiest for you, that is in your project:

```
<properties>
    <spring-restdocs.version>1.2.2.RELEASE</spring-restdocs.version>
</properties>
```

Note that this does assume you're using spring-boot-starter-parent, which seems like a reasonable assumption. I believe that will get you the mockmvc dependency as well, so you can remove your existing declaration of that dependency. This [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html) might also be useful. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Andy for catching and fixing my typo!